# Yii2 Custom validation on scenario not working

Tags: yii2

I am creating a function for validation data on given scenario but its not working.
Model code :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
     //   ['session_key','deal_id','required'],
        ['data', 'validateCart'],
        [['session_key','deal_id'], 'safe'],
       // [['cartfood','session_key'], 'required','on'=>'sessionapi'],
        ['cartfood', 'myvalidation', 'on' => 'sessionapi'],
        ];
    }

 public function myvalidation($attribute, $params){
          if (!$this->hasErrors()) { 
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($params); die;
          }
     }
```

Controller : code

```
public function actionPayinapp(){
        $data=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();    
        $cart=json_decode($data['cartfood']);
        $model=new Cart();  
        $model->scenario = 'sessionapi';
        $dataarr = array();
        $model->data = $cart;  
 if($model->validate())
        { 
die(ok);
}
}
```

I want `myvalidation` run on `sessionapi` scenario but it's not working.

Comment: Try :  ['cartfood', 'myvalidation', 'on' => ['sessionapi']],

Comment: @YasinPatel Not Working

Comment: $model=new Cart();    $model->scenario = 'sessionapi';

Comment: put this lines above all code in action

Comment: @YasinPatel no luck thanks for your support.

Comment: [['cartfood'],
function ($attribute, $params) {
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {

Comment: is it going in the validate() if condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Your Controller Code As: -[SkipOnEmpty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnEmpty-detail)

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        //   ['session_key','deal_id','required'],
        ['data', 'validateCart'],
        [['session_key','deal_id'], 'safe'],
        // [['cartfood','session_key'], 'required','on'=>'sessionapi'],
        //you have to apply skipOnEmpty in your rules as
        ['cartfood', 'myvalidation', 'on' => 'sessionapi' ,'skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}

public function myvalidation($attribute, $params){
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($params); die;
    }
}
```